# Pictures not visible in Windows 8 Picture App

Tags: windows-8, pictures, windows-store-app, folder-redirection

I changed the default system folder `C:\Users\myuser\Pictures` to another folder on an externat SD-card D:\Eigene Bilder`. After doing that there where no pictures in my Windows-8 Picture-App anymore.

even after changing back the default folder, there are still no pics in my Library in the App.

How can I tell the App that the pictures are back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not solved even after a system restart. But after just waiting some minutes and maybe because I connected the device to the internet, all of a sudden the pictures were found in the library again.

Maybe it just took some minutes until the system scanned the library again.